# Android scrollview width full screen, also Uri.parse(location)

Tags: java, android

i think this question has been asked alot, and yes i have been looking for hours here, nothing really helped me..
I can show the problem with this picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/toI4E.png

sorry that i give link( i don't have enough reputation for image)

As you can see, the width doesn't fit the whole screen..
Trust me, i tried so much things to fix it:
fill_parent
match_parent
gravity=fill
viewport=true
and more..

So here is my XML code for this moment:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".Succes" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/google"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickGoogle"
        android:text="Go google" />

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickSudan"
        android:text="Go to Sudan!" />

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />


        <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickAwesome"
        android:text="Awesome button" />

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Rate me!"
        />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/lol2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickHai"
        android:text="Hai" />

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />

        <SeekBar 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickSuper"
        android:text="Super button" />

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickOut"
        android:text="Go back" />



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I also have another problem(not connected to first one):

```
public void onClickSudan(View view)
{

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("GO TO SUDAN?");
    dialog.setMessage("Are you really sure go to Sudan?" +
    " By pressing yes you will not have the ability to come back!" +
    " Please think good before clicking yes(think really good).");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
        {
            //if clicked okay, go to there ;o
            Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:18.130191,31.683355");
            Intent start = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);

            startActivity(start);
        }
        });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("No.", null);

    AlertDialog dialog2 = dialog.create();
    dialog2.show();


}
```

The Uri cannot recognize this coordinates, what is wrong here?
The application crashes.
If the problem is with coordinates so how to get correct coordinates with google maps?

Thanks (:

Comment: Please post your entire layout xml file.

Comment: Yes sorry, i edited (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two questions, two answers. Your `ScrollView` is not taking up the entire width of your screen because your top-level `RelativeLayout` has padding set. Remove the `padding` attributes and the `ScrollView` will fit the entire screen. That said, I have no idea why you'd want your `ScrollView` to take up the entire screen width. Seems like it wouldn't look very nice...

Comment: Wow thanks alot!! This worked (:
And i prefer the ScrollView to take up the entire screen width, looks better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), you must prepend your location with "geo:" for it to be a valid URI. You should separate your questions into separate SO posts.

Comment: Does it give an exception? Scratch that, of course it gives an exception. _What is the exception._ Update your code as well, so we can see exactly what changes you made.

Comment: Can you post the results of your logcat as well? It seems like Uri.parse should work fine.

Comment: You mean the Console?
The last message i can see there is ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.tomato.potato/.MainActivity

Comment: If your app is crashing, a stack trace should be showing up in the console. Try scrolling around?

Comment: Nothing appears there.
Looks like syntax problem, the URI cannot recognize this string, what is the syntax for coordinates than?